# How populate List Data from Service in Angular

Tags: angular

I am pretty much New to Angular, I have a list that I need to show on Screen, I was able to get the list show with hard coded data, but I need to bring the data from my service that is calling the API, that part is done too. My problem is how replace the hard coded with that.

My list has 3 column: Boards - Id - Status

```
 export class CardComponent implements OnInit
   {
    @Input()
    public agent: Agent;
    public Boards: string = '';
    public Id: number = 0;
    public status: string = '';
```

and this is the List with hard coded value:

```
  public BoardsList: any[] = [
    {
        "Id": "123R",
        "Boards": "TestB",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": "345F",
        "Boards": "TestV",
        "status": 0
    }
];
```

This is HTML page:

```
  <div class="_header">
    <div class="_item">Boards</div>
    <div class="_item">ID</div>
    <div class="_item">Status</div>
</div>
<div class="_data"
     *ngFor="let mLSBoards of BoardsList">
    <div class="_data__item">{{mLSBoards.Boards}}</div>
    <div class="_data__item">{{mLSBoards.Id}}</div>
    <div class="_data__item">{{mLSBoards.status}}</div>
</div>
```

This is what I see in Screen:

```
       Boards       ID       Status
       TestB        123R      1
       TestV        345F      0
```

I tried to create a method that is returning List from Services but not sure how (This code is not working but this.Agent.Boards has that 3 field I need, I imported the service here as well.

```
private GetBoardsList(BoardsList: any[]): void
{
    this.Agent.Boards.forEach(x =>
    {
        x.Id,
        x.Board,
        x.status

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this.

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public BoardsList: any[] = [
    {
      "Id": "123R",
      "Boards": "TestB",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "Id": "345F",
      "Boards": "TestV",
      "status": 0
    }
  ];
  constructor() { }

  getList() {
    return this.BoardsList;
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private _listData;

  constructor(
    private _dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._listData = this._dataService.getList();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="item">Boards</div>
  <div class="item">ID</div>
  <div class="item">Status</div>
</div>

<div class="data"
     *ngFor="let mLSBoards of _listData">
    <div class="data__item">{{mLSBoards.Boards}}</div>
    <div class="data__item">{{mLSBoards.Id}}</div>
    <div class="data__item">{{mLSBoards.status}}</div>
</div>
```

app.component.scss

```
.header,
.data {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8e7lva)

let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great help, my method signature in Service is like getRealEstateAgent(request: GetRealEstateAgentRequest): Observable<GetRealEstateAgentResponse>    How I can build a request?  and export interface GetRealEstateAgentRequest
{
 guid: string;
}